# Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined. React+Jest+Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I am rendering a react Component `App.tsx` which uses `useEffect` hook. Inside the `useEffect`, it makes an async call updates the state `delivery` defined in `App.tsx`. At first render, `delivery` is undefined, but after next re-render, it is defined.

```
const App = () => {
  const [delivery, setDelivery] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setup()
  }, [])

  const setup = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await someAsyncCall()
      setDelivery(response)    
      setLoading(true)
    /// Other functionality
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }finally{
        setLoading(false)
    }
    
  }
  return (
      <>
      {loading? <div>Loading!!</div>
        : <div>App has loaded with {delivery.displayName} {delivery.id}</div>  
    }
      </>
  )
}
```

How to write unit test so that it re-renders with right value? Right now I get `Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined]`

Unit Test I wrote :

```
describe('test', ()=>{
    it("mounts", ()=>{
       const wrapper =  mount(<App />)
    })
})
```

Any thoughts on how to re-render? I read `wrapper.update()` could be used. I was wondering how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this solve the problem?

```
return (
  <>
    {loading || !delivery ? <div>Loading!!</div>
      : <div>App has loaded with {delivery.displayName} {delivery.id}</div>  
        }
  </>
)
```